# question about a Rosenthal inequality

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing, nonparametric-density

What is the usefulness of Rosenthal inequalities in (kernel) density estimation
[image]

where $\xi _i .... \xi _n$ are independent random variables, $\mathbb{E}\xi_{i} =0$ and $c(p)=15p/lnp$ for $p>2$

Why we say that $c(p)=15p/lnp$ is ''the best-know constant'' ?
Some help would be appreciated

Comment: Some expansion of this is surely and sorely needed. You are unlikely to get personal tutorials by return just by mentioning some technical terms. In particular, what are Rosenthal inequalities? What specifically do you not understand?

Comment: It would be helpful if you cited where these equations came from. Chances are it would make more sense in context.

Comment: It's this [paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2243635?sid=21105583440343&uid=4&uid=2&uid=3737768)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about kernel density estimation, but Rosenthal inequality is very useful in getting bounds on the following type of probabilities:

$$P\left(\left|\sum_{i=1} X_{i}\right|>\varepsilon\right).$$

Combining Markov inequality with Rosenthal you get

\begin{align}
P\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}\right|>\varepsilon\right)\le \frac{c(p)^p}{\varepsilon^p}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nE|X_i|^p+\left(\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i^2 \right)^{p/2}\right)
\end{align}

If you control $E|X_i|^p$  and $EX_i^2=1$ you might get a useful bound. As some commenters noted it depends on the context, so this inequality is just another tool in the box. But it can be very useful: for example, I used it extensively in my Ph.D. thesis.